# Retrieve Client machine infomation in asp.net

Tags: .net, client, client-side

I have developed a web form using asp.net to retrieve machine information (RAM,HDD space, Processor...etc) But when I host the web form, it only retrieves the values of Server machine. How can I get those information by logging in to that form from any machine?

Comment: pages run server end and will encounter issues trying to access the client too much - as due to too many people abusing it, much assess is restricted

Comment: I have developed this for a company. They needed to take an Inventory, so in order to do that they need to access that web form from each & every PC. The web form is hosted in the main server, so it only retrieves the information about the server PC

Comment: Your code is set to run on the server, so it will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put you can't do that. Only possibility is to use ActiveX, that will require a user to run IE (and no other browser) and allow your website to access that information.

Most users will not allow you to get that information (for security reasons) so you can't count on it.

Comment: any sample application of it?? because I'm not that so comfortable with activeX :(

Comment: Here's an example how to get client MAC address using C# and ActiveX. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/ahsanm.m/how-to-get-the-mac-address-of-system-using-Asp-NetC-Sharp/

Answer (score 1):

Asp.net page always lives at server side. HTML is product of this server and by default you can get only limited information from the client machine like this:

```
        string browserInfo =
             "RemoteUser=" + context.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_USER"] + ";\n"
            + "RemoteHost=" + context.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_HOST"] + ";\n"
            + "Type=" + context.Request.Browser.Type + ";\n"
            + "Name=" + context.Request.Browser.Browser + ";\n"
            + "Version=" + context.Request.Browser.Version + ";\n"
            + "MajorVersion=" + context.Request.Browser.MajorVersion + ";\n"
            + "MinorVersion=" + context.Request.Browser.MinorVersion + ";\n"
            + "Platform=" + context.Request.Browser.Platform + ";\n"
            + "SupportsCookies=" + context.Request.Browser.Cookies + ";\n"
            + "SupportsJavaScript=" + context.Request.Browser.EcmaScriptVersion.ToString() + ";\n"
            + "SupportsActiveXControls=" + context.Request.Browser.ActiveXControls + ";\n"
            + "SupportsJavaScriptVersion=" + context.Request.Browser["JavaScriptVersion"] + "\n";
```

If you want to get RAM,HDD,... you should develop activex control and client must to install it.

Comment: Thank you @Gregor Primar.. By the way, do I need to add any references?

Comment: Inside page context you do not need to add any reference for code block above. Just for info HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;